# Identifying rows which don't match a master row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, query, except

I'm comparing a bunch of tables from different databases on different servers to a Master record. I need to know which servers, identified by `locationID`, have the non-matching rows because they might need maintenance.

I've got a simple `EXCEPT` query where I compare a table where each row is the configuration from each server; `table1` has one row per server with all configuration plus `locationID` which is a column that tells me which server it is. I compare these all to a `table1_master` table which has the right settings, but I exclude the `locationID` since it won't match.

Simple query below:

```
SELECT everything, but, locationID
FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT everything, but, locationID
FROM table1_master
```

There's only *one* master row I compare all servers to, and I don't select it's `locationID` here.

This is an example of the rows I'm comparing. Each has a primary key, a single column `varchar` and a giant list of that's dozens of columns. I want to compare all columns *except* LocationID, but I need LocationID to identify the rows.

```
LocationID             setting    setting    setting     setting
CS02      C            Y           Y         Y           Y
CS03      C            Y           Y         Y           Y
CS06      C            Y           N         Y           Y
```

In this example say CS02 is my Master record, so since all settings are the same in CS02 and CS03, those rows don't show up, but CS06's does. But in my `EXCEPT` query, I'm not actually catching LocationID so I don't actually know which row was returned.

This returns the rows I need but NOT the `locationID`, so I don't know which rows are wrong. Is there any way I can include `locationID` in the results set while kicking out the matching rows?

The solution I thought of was to make a row for each server in the `table1_master` table, so each `locationID` is represented, but they all have the same data other than that. My `EXCLUDE` query should then return the `locationID` and my info, but is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you show a few rows of sample data and your desired results from the query? Also can you explain what column(s) make up the key in each table? It may be that `EXCEPT` is not the syntactic sugar you want or need in this case.

Comment: Still hard to visualize without sample data / desired results.

Comment: Thanks, from this sample data, which rows do you want returned? They all seem to have the same settings, I assume you meant to show at least one row where at least one setting was different?

Comment: Ben, data types of the `settingx` columns?

Comment: @AaronBertrand nvarchars and ints, with some odds and ends like datetimes. Could be anything, multiple tables actually.

Comment: You'll also want to consider whether any of the columns are NULLable. This can affect how you do your comparisons (ideally the columns will all be defined as NOT NULL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do this with dynamic SQL without having to manually build out all the column names.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @c1 NVARCHAR(MAX), @c2 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @c1 = N'', @c2 = N'';

SELECT 
  @c1 = @c1 + ',' + QUOTENAME(name),
  @c2 = @c2 + ' AND m.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = s.' + QUOTENAME(name)
 FROM sys.columns
 WHERE name <> 'LocationID'
 AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table1');

SET @sql = ';WITH s AS (
       SELECT ' + STUFF(@c1, 1, 1, '') + ' FROM dbo.table1
       EXCEPT 
       SELECT ' + STUFF(@c1, 1, 1, '') + ' FROM dbo.table1_master
     ) 
     SELECT m.LocationID
 FROM s INNER JOIN dbo.table1 AS m ON 1 = 1
 ' + @c2;

SELECT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You can take the output of this query as is and store the query somewhere, or you can comment out the `SELECT` and uncomment the `EXEC` and leave it as permanent dynamic SQL - in this case it will automatically adapt to column changes in the two tables.

Another idea (assuming LocationID is unique) - and it occurred to me you may want to include the master row so you can quickly spot the columns that are different:

```
  ;WITH c AS 
  (
    SELECT t.LocationID, m.setting1, m.setting2, ...
      FROM dbo.table1 AS t CROSS JOIN dbo.table1_master AS m
  )
  SELECT DISTINCT src = '> master', setting1, setting2, ...
    FROM c
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT RTRIM(LocationID), setting1, setting2, ...
      FROM dbo.table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT RTRIM(LocationID), setting1, setting2, ...
      FROM c
  )
  ORDER BY src;
```

This version is a little cheaper (mostly by avoiding the `DISTINCT` against the master table, at the cost of needing to specify all of the columns one more time - which again you can automate as per above):

```
  ;WITH m AS 
  (
    SELECT setting1, setting2, ... 
      FROM dbo.table1_master
  ),
  c AS 
  (
    SELECT src = RTRIM(t.LocationID), m.setting1, m.setting2, ...
      FROM dbo.table1 AS t CROSS JOIN m
  )
  SELECT src = '> master', setting1, setting2, ...
    FROM m
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT RTRIM(LocationID), setting1, setting2, ...
      FROM dbo.table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT src, setting1, setting2, ...
      FROM c
  )
  ORDER BY src;
```

However all of these options are poorer performers with worse plans than Rachel's simple `LEFT JOIN`. I tried to stick to the theme of using `EXCEPT` even though it is more about syntax than performance.

The key takeaway is that if the column count is too high to deal with manually, you can use the dynamic SQL approach above to construct whatever query you want to use - and you can do that one time and store the result, or have the code generated every time. To generate Rachel's query using dynamic SQL, not much needs to change:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @and NVARCHAR(MAX), @anycol NVARCHAR(128);
SELECT @sql = N'', @and = N'';

SELECT @and = @and + ' AND t.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' = m.' + QUOTENAME(name)
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table1_master');

SELECT TOP (1) @anycol = QUOTENAME(name)
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table1_master')
  ORDER BY name;

SET @sql = 'SELECT locationID
FROM dbo.table1 AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table1_master AS m ON 1 = 1' 
  + @and + ' WHERE m.' + @anycol + ' IS NULL;';

SELECT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Impressive, I would have never even thought to do this. Toying with this now

Comment: This solution was particularly excellent as I can use a variable as the table name, so I make one change and fetch totally different tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

- Creating a `Hash` field that is a persisted computed column with a definition along the lines of `HASHBYTES('SHA1', Field1 + Field2 + Field3...)`
- Comparing just that `HASH` value from your "master" to your other records
- Displaying all the actual values from non-matching rows

Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE HashField <> (SELECT Hashfield FROM Table1_Master)
```

Comment: Hm never used hash before, that sounds perfect. I'll see if I can make it work

Comment: @BenBrocka it's not super fast to run (hashes are purposefully slow) so make sure you persist it if at all possible.

Comment: I'm only looking to query these servers and update 4 times a day right now so it shouldn't be a big deal. Querying 40 servers, half with Ping > 2000ms CPU/I/O speed is never the bottleneck...

Comment: @BenBrocka OK good deal.  This should work just fine then, and you could just put it into a view if you wanted for something on that scale.

Comment: No concerns over collisions?

Comment: @AaronBertrand `SHA1` has a minimum collision rate in lab tests of 2^61, so unless every person on the planet has 337,000,000 computers and Ben needs to test them all, it should be good here.  The theoretical collision rate is 2^80.

Comment: Okay, someone on SO recently described a collision problem that I couldn't reproduce, but it still made me a little leery.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would definitely be worried about it with higher data volumes.  We have a very large table where I work with around 2b rows that we use a hash of several values with no issue for comparisons of this sort as well.  I think `MD5` has a lot more problems with that.

Comment: Not trying to be a PITA, but what about data types? If Column1, Column2 etc. are not strings... how do you implement the hash? RTRIM() on every column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Wouldn't work if they aren't strings unless you convert. I assumed from the example given that they were all `CHAR(1)`

Comment: Well they are settings, so I suspect they are `VARCHAR(something)`. In which case I wouldn't trust the hash there either, since a hash of `'xx' + 'yy'` is the same as a hash of `'xxy' + 'y'`... that might be unlikely, but it might not.

Comment: FWIW this performs on par with Rachel's join. Just not sure if the hashing will work if any columns are variable length.

Comment: You also have to deal with NULLs when hashing the concatenation of the columns. If either of the columns is NULL, the result of the hash is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just joining the two tables on every column (or using a where statement) and selecting items that don't exist in the 2nd table?

```
SELECT locationID
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1_master 
    ON table1.a = table1_master.a
    AND table1.b = table1_master.b
    AND table1.c = table1_master.c
WHERE table1_master.a is null
```

It might not be pretty, but it should work

Comment: I suspect the problem is there are a LOT of columns and Ben liked how much simpler `EXCEPT` made it seem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought that too, but it sounds like this is some kind of maintenance script, or one-time thing, so copy/paste doesn't seem like a terrible option for that. Should be fairly quick to copy/paste the `SELECT` columns and do a Find/Replace or two on the comma to replace it with the join statement

Comment: +1 for both simplicity and performance (see the edit to my answer).